# Is there an open-source equivalent to Amazon S3?

Tags: filesystems, amazon-s3, storage, bucket

Is there an open-source equivalent to the Amazon S3 storage service running under Linux?

For example a bucket-based file system like:

- store file -> get unique id
- access file by unique id
- delete file by unique id
- query files by timestamp
- ...

Thanks.

Comment: Since I can't add an answer, I write this comment: Minio is an Amazon S3 compatible object storage server. https://minio.io

Answer (score 11):

[Riak CS](http://basho.com/products/riakcs/) is a new Amazon S3 API-compatible product for your own cloud. It's not open-source, but it may be a viable alternative for your consideration.

Comment: It's open sourced now

Answer (score 9):

OpenStack also does [object storage](https://www.openstack.org/software/releases/victoria/components/swift).

There was also [Eucalyptus](https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus), but that seems to be dead.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your answers and sorry for not being clear about my problem.

Currently i have about 4TB of image files spread over 3 servers.
My application spreads these files randomly. On which server the file is located, is stored at the mysql database (replicated to each of these servers).
The image files are served by nginx and php directly from these servers (no proxy).
When one of these servers crashes, i have no failover and no redundancy.
Of course i can recover anything from backups, but 1 to 1.5TB of data on each server need much time to recover.

After a bit of research, i found [MogileFS](http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/) as the optimal solution.